# Making changes to node-red settings.js not getting affected?

Tags: node-red

I'm actually having a `node-red` instance running on windows and I'm pretty new to this. So expect me to be a new bie.

I tried changing the **editorTheme** plus the **paletteCategories** in the *settings.js* within the installation directory as per the [doc](https://nodered.org/docs/configuration).

But then when I tried to restart the instance and check the for the changes in the `node-red` UI, I couldn't see any.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: in exactly which directory did you change `settings.js` and update the question to show what you actually changed.

Comment: @hardillb Oh thanks. Figured it out, It was pointing to a wrong **settings file**.

Comment: Can you add an answer explaing the difference to help anybody else that comes across this question.

Comment: @hardillb done :) Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I say that I changed **settings.js** in the installation directory, it should
 actually be the **settings.js** in the `.node-red` folder (where the 
flow file is stored also).

If you look in the console when you start `node-red` it will tell you 
which *settings.js* is being loaded. Apparently, mine was pointing to a different one, not the one within the `node-red`  directory which I was running.

Hope this helps!